# UIMA RUTA wordlist matching issue

Tags: uima, ruta, word-list

I am trying to match some multi-word tokens using UIMA RUTA 2.6.0. And there are some phrases that are partially equal to each other, e. g. in the same file I has following entries: "includes the", "include the", "in this", "in the".

There is next piece of text in my input file: "*1. "Agents or employees" includes the directors...*". Obviously, there is a "**includes the**" match, but if other above 3 entries are present in wordlist then no match will be found. Moreover, the ordering of those entries in wordlist does not depend on matching success: it always fails.

And this issue occurs not only in single file. So, the question: how can I fix it? May be some settings of RUTA annotator?

Comment: This is most likely caused by the whitespaces in the wordlist. Try to remove all of them. If it works, you can solve it with the config param dictRemoveWS.

Comment: @peter, This is unusual logic, but it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, it sounds not reasonable but the wordlist can also be applied on patterns of whitespaces thus they cannot be ignored in general. Maybe I set the parameter to true by default in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespaces in the wordlist can lead to missed matches. If the whitespaces are not important, set the configuration parameter 'dictRemoveWS' to true.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: If Spaces are important and we put it in csv, Will above issue remains same or not ?